# Usage: "as soon as practicable" vs "as soon as is practicable"

Tags: phrase-usage

Advice is sought in differentiating the usage of "as soon as practicable" and "as soon as is practicable". A brief research on internet reveals that use of "as soon as practicable" is more than 10 times more popular than "as soon as is practicable" (Google search: 4,286,000 vs 344,000) However, "as soon as is practicable" is more popular in legal documents, such as law, contracts and etc. Grateful if sources could cite on the usage and difference in these two phrases. Thank you.

Comment: Do you require your usage to conform with "formal" legal documents in some context? If not specifically, then there is no advantage gained by including "is". It's worth noting that legal documents can be redundantly verbose quite often.

Comment: "As soon as it becomes even marginally practicable."

Comment: I'm a lawyer. I was about to write "as soon as is practicable" in an email, thought to myself "is that right? or is it too formal?", did a search and ended up here. More evidence of a legal correlation, but I have no idea why. Probably just a self-reinforcing bit of legal culture to use that phrasing.